# How to read PostgreSQL refcursor in SSRS

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services, greenplum, ref-cursor

I am trying to have an SSRS dataset read from a PostgreSQL function which returns a refcursor (using Pivotal Greenplum) but I'm having terrible luck with it. I've tried fetching from it, but to no avail. I've tried using  the way you would do it with Oracle's db but it just doesn't work the same. Does anyone have any insights as to how or if this is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok so I don't think this should only be Greenplum specific but more along the lines of having it work with PostgreSQL in general.

Comment: Greenplum is not good for cursors and this is not a recommended way to work with data as it is extremely slow. Without the detailed use case description I cannot advice you an appropriate solution, but in short in MPP databases you should avoid the cursors by all means